Showing error : "Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source"
When I am trying to use any command like sudo apt-get update then I am getting
Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ noble-pgdg: /usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.asc != /usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.gpg
The list of sources could not be read.
Please, I need your help with this.
